# Combining Python Request - files and integer

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to make a request for a form-data type. The request worked previously when it was just two files being used for the request. However, now an ID has to be inputted in the request also, and it won't work.

I have tried lots of different options of trying to get this to work, the ID is an input in a separate file, same as 'file_a' and 'file_b'. However, it is erroring with the ID form data field.

```py
url = url
headers = {"Authorization": Access_token}
files = [('file_a', open(file_a, 'rb')), ('file_b', open(file_b, 'rb')), ('ID', ID)]
response = requests.post(url=url, files=files, headers=headers)
print(response.content)
```

I am expecting a response json string, however getting no response as the request is not working due to the ID integer field.

Comment: "the request is not working due to the ID integer field." What do you mean by this, do you have a response.status_code or an error message ?

Answer (score 0):

From your code sample, it seems *ID* is a file, but you probably want to pass it as form-encoded data to `data` argument in `requests.post`.

To do this create a dictionary containing the name of the field and its value:

```py
url = url

headers = {"Authorization": Access_token}

files = [('file_a', open(file_a, 'rb')), ('file_b', open(file_b, 'rb'))]

data = {'ID', ID}  # here's ID value

response = requests.post(url=url, files=files, headers=headers)

print('status code:', response.status_code)
```

[Here](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests) you can find the documentation you need to send form data.

Please, let me know whether this helps you or if you need further help.